# PHP: Loop Through Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to be able to loop over only a section at a time to populate content for some Tabs. What would be the best way to loop over just the `Videos` array?

This is what I've tried:

```
foreach ($result['videos'] as $r) {
    $content = '<tr>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $r['id'] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $r['name'] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $r['body'] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $r['created'] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $r['modified'] . '</td>';
    $content .= '</tr>';
    echo $content;

}



Array
(
    [images] => Array(...)

    [videos] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [type] => 2
                    [name] => My Video
                    [body] => my_video.flv
                    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2012-04-07 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [type] => 2
                    [name] => Yet another video
                    [body] => my_vid_man.flv
                    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [type] => 2
                    [name] => asasd
                    [body] => asdasd
                    [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                )

        )
```

Comment: it looks correct i'd search the error elsewhere + pls shorten array 1-2 elements are enough to represent the array structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = array(...);

foreach( $result['videos'] as $video )
{
  // $video is each individual item in the videos array
}
```

Comment: It already is an array called $result ... and I've done that exact foreach and it didn't product anything.

Comment: then give us your foreach code there is probably an error in there then

Comment: @dcolumbus it works perfect here: http://phphulp.wouterj.nl/stack-multi-arr.php (for the source, put `?source` behind the url)