# PHP Looping through a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi I have this multi dimensional array in PHP:

```
$team_arrays = array (
                        "lakers" => array (
                                        24 => "Bryant",
                                        6  => "Price",
                                        17 => "Lin"
                        ),

                        "knicks" => array (
                                        7 => "Anthony",
                                       22 => "Shumpert",
                                       12 => "Jackson"
                        ),

                        "thunder" => array (
                                       35 => "Durant",
                                       0  => "Westbrook",
                                       13 => "Miller"
                        )
                    );
```

I wanted to display something like this:

Team Name: lakers

1. Bryant = 24
2. Price = 6
3. Lin = 17

Team Name: knicks

1. Anthony = 7
2. Shumpert = 22
3. Jackson = 12

...

This is the code that I tried but seems not to work:

```
foreach ($team_arrays as $names => $team) {
                        echo "<h2>Team Name: " . $names . "</h2>";
                        echo "<ol>";
                            foreach ($team_arrays as $jersey => $names) {
                                echo "<li>" . $names . " = " . $jersey . "</li>";
                            }
                        echo "</ol>";
                    }
```

It generates this kind of error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

Would anyone tries for a help. Please.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066043/php-loop-through-multidimensional-array) from other question but seems I can't relate to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one small problem in your code

```
foreach ($team_arrays as $jersey => $names) {
         ^ // again looping over the same outer array?
```

That inner loop is wrong, you should loop over `$team` and not `$team_arrays` because your outer loop picks up each team using `$team` variable.

```
foreach ($team as $jersey => $names) {
```

Rest of your code and logic is already fine.

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wXvZny)**

Answer (score 0):

You  need to change this line from;

```
 foreach ($team_arrays as $jersey => $names) {
```

to:

```
   foreach ($team as $jersey => $names) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `foreach ($team as $jersey => $names)`

**Try this :**

```
$team_arrays = array (
                        "lakers" => array (
                                        24 => "Bryant",
                                        6  => "Price",
                                        17 => "Lin"
                        ),

                        "knicks" => array (
                                        7 => "Anthony",
                                       22 => "Shumpert",
                                       12 => "Jackson"
                        ),

                        "thunder" => array (
                                       35 => "Durant",
                                       0  => "Westbrook",
                                       13 => "Miller"
                        )
                    );

 foreach ($team_arrays as $names => $team) {
                        echo "<h2>Team Name: " . $names . "</h2>";
                        echo "<ol>";
                            foreach ($team as $jersey => $names) {
                                echo "<li>" . $names . " = " . $jersey . "</li> \n";
                            }
                        echo "</ol>";
                    }                   
 ?>
```